# SQL 2008 Encryption Scan

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, encryption

We recently upgraded a database server from SQL 2005 to SQL 2008 64 bit. CPU utilization is oftentimes running at 100% on all four processors now (this never happended on the SQL 2005 server). When I run sp_lock I see a number of processes waiting on a resource called [ENCRYPTION_SCAN]. I am not using any SQL 2008 encryption features. Does anyone know why I would have tasks waiting on this resource? It appears that whenever I have four processes waiting on this resource, CPU hits 100% on all four processors.

Comment: You could also try asking this at www.ServerFault.com

Answer (score 5):

I've been seeing this same question crop up in a few different places.  It hasn't been proven definitively yet, but it looks like long-running BULK INSERT or SORT operations could be pessimistically holding an ENCRYPTION_SCAN lock in order to prevent an encryption scan from starting in the middle of the operation.  Look for a blog from CSS on this in the near future, I'll link back to it here when/if it comes out.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2016/04/19/why-do-we-see-encryption_scan-locks-in-a-sql-server/

Answer (score 2):

> Transparent data encryption (TDE) performs real-time I/O encryption and decryption of the data and log files.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx

Do you have this enabled?

Update:

Can you tell what operations are being blocked?  e.g., inserts, deletes, updates, index scans, etc..

TDE is the only scenario where I've ever seen any reference to an "encryption scan".  A quick search only validates this:

> ... The server starts a background thread (called the encryption scan or scan) ... . While the DDL executes, an update lock is taken on the database. The encryption scan, which runs asynchronously to the DDL, takes a shared lock. All normal operations that do not conflict with these locks can proceed. Excluded operations include modifying the file structure and detaching the database.
>
> [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278098.aspx)

This makes it sound like the ongoing "encryption scan" you're seeing implies that encryption is being enabled and disabled repeatedly on the database, or the key is changing, because these delays should only be seen when the encryption state changes.  Either that or you have a very large database, and when it eventually finishes the problem will just go away.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT DB_NAME(e.database_id) AS DatabaseName,
            e.database_id,
            e.encryption_state,
    CASE e.encryption_state
                WHEN 0 THEN 'No key present - encryption unavailable'
                WHEN 1 THEN 'Unencrypted'
                WHEN 2 THEN 'Encryption in progress'
                WHEN 3 THEN 'Encrypted'
                WHEN 4 THEN 'Key change in progress'
                WHEN 5 THEN 'Decryption in progress'
    END AS encryption_state_desc,
            c.name,
            e.percent_complete
    FROM sys.dm_database_encryption_keys AS e 
    LEFT JOIN master.sys.certificates AS c 
    ON e.encryptor_thumbprint = c.thumbprint
```

Comment: There's no rows returned when I run that query. I believe now that I was mistaken when I thought there was a correlation between the tasks waiting on ENCRYPTION_SCAN and the high CPU utilization. It appears that I always see this ENCRYPTION_SCAN for the process running an sp_lock command, no matter which database I happen to be pointing to in query analyzer. Maybe it's just something that sp_lock uses?? Thanks for your help on this.